# building and accessing a list of types at compile time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to achieve the following using c++ template metaprogramming. I wish to build up a list of types and then collect these types together and do further compile-time processing on the list. So for example:

foo.h:

```
class Foo { ... };
// INSERT ANY CODE HERE
```

bar.h:

```
class Bar { ... };
// INSERT ANY CODE HERE
```

main.h:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

struct list_of_types {
  typedef /* INSERT ANY CODE HERE */ type;
};
```

I can insert any code into the slots above, so long as list_of_types::type resolves to some representation (e.g. a boost::mpl::vector) of a list containing the types Foo and Bar. The following restrictions apply:

1. The code in foo.h should not know about the code in bar.h, and vice versa. It should be possible to change the order of #include directives in main.h and not change any other code.
2. The code in main.h should not have to change if I include further headers that add further types to the list.
3. The list of types must be available at *compile time*. I am planning to do further metaprogramming involving the list.

Comment: @Jarod42 How does `std::tuple` help here? Point 2 is a very sensible requirement – this makes the code open to extension without requiring change to existing code.

Comment: Loki typelist? http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00554.html

Comment: @AdamBurry: the main challenge is finding a way to build up lists in this way. There are many ways of *representing* lists of types (such as boost::mpl::vector or the possibilities you mentioned), but this is not the core issue.

Comment: It seems to me that you are going to need code in your headers to register the types with the type list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A solution utilizing a common header, variadic templates and a macro:

```
// Header common.h

// A distinct Void type
struct Void {};

template <typename ...> struct concat;

template <template <typename ...> class List, typename T>
struct concat<List<Void>, T>
{
    typedef List<T> type;
};

template <template <typename ...> class List, typename ...Types, typename T>
struct concat<List<Types...>, T>
{
    typedef List<Types..., T> type;
};

template <typename...> struct TypeList {};

template <>
struct TypeList<Void> {};
typedef TypeList<Void> TypelistVoid;
#define TYPE_LIST TypelistVoid
```

```
// Header foo.h
#include <common.h>

class Foo { };

typedef typename concat<TYPE_LIST, Foo>::type TypeListFoo;
#undef TYPE_LIST
#define TYPE_LIST TypeListFoo
```

```
// Header bar.h
#include <common.h>

class Bar { };

typedef typename concat<TYPE_LIST, Bar>::type TypeListBar;
#undef TYPE_LIST
#define TYPE_LIST TypeListBar
```

```
// Header main.h 
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

struct list_of_types {
    typedef TYPE_LIST type;
};
// Or just typedef TYPE_LIST list_of_types;

// Test
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <template <typename ...> class List, typename T, typename ...Types>
void info();

template <typename T, typename ...Types>
inline void info(TypeList<T, Types...>) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    info(TypeList<Types...>());
}

template <typename T>
inline void info(TypeList<T>) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    info(list_of_types::type());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes this does it. Good idea to use a preprocesor symbol to store the changing global "state" of the list. As an aside, I was hoping to be able to wrap up the code that gets put into foo.h and bar.h with a macro like REGISTER_TYPE, but I guess with this scheme that isn't quite possible. You've definitely answered my question though - thank you!

Comment: I've found a different solution which only needs macros not includes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24092292/1020667

Comment: Does this need the `Void` type? Can't you just specialize for `List<>` instead of `List<Void>`?

Answer (score -2):

```
template <typename ... Types>
void info(TypeList<Types...>) {

  std::initializer_list<std::string> ls { typeid(Types).name() ... };

  for (auto& name : ls)
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  info(TYPE_LIST());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about your answer so people will no why it is a good one.

Comment: just a small improvement to the above solution, by using initializer_list, you don't have to write 3 info() to expand the template params.

Comment: how does this relate to the question ?