# c++ type list accumulation

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

I've begun to play around with lists of types such as boost::mpl::vector.

One thing I'd like to be able to do is aggregate the types across multiple headers. For example I define the

header1:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<> typelist;
```

header2-n:

```
// Fails to compile, cannot redefine typelist
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<typelist, my_type_i>::type typelist
```

It seems like I should be able to do such a thing at compile time as its still just type manipulation, but I'm not sure if there is a way.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701798/building-and-accessing-a-list-of-types-at-compile-time/18704609#18704609

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks, that worked. I suppose this question should be closed as a duplicate