# Building a list of types during compile time - no C++11

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'd like to do exact [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704609/2566773) to get a list of types/classes.  But I cannot use C++11.  Any suggestion how I can append type to the template list?

Edit: some code to what I'd like to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

typedef boost::mpl::vector<> type1;
// supposed I'd like to have this as a #define macro so someone can call
// REGISTER_CLASS(A) and push the type into a list
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type1, A> type2;
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type2, B> type3;
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type3, C> type4;

template <typename T> struct wrap {};

struct Print
{
      template <typename T> void operator()( wrap<T> t ) const
      {
            cout << typeid( T ).name() << endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
      // this doesn't compile because type4 is a sequence of sequence
      // supposed, I need to "flatten" this list so it's eqv to vector<A,B,C>
      boost::mpl::for_each<type4, wrap<boost::mpl::placeholders::_1> >( Print() );

      // second problem is that I'd like to have typedef of 1 typelist only, not
      // type1, type2, ... typeN, since I don't know the exact number of classes

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/list.html)?

Comment: yes, though I'm quite new to metaprogramming.  Any further pointers appreciated.  How do I append type T to a e.g. vector, without re-typedef the type list?

Comment: What do you mean by "append type T to a e.g. vector"? Can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish? I don't see where the vector comes to play right now

Comment: @surfcode Template metaprogramming is 100% functional - which means everything is *immutable.* An immutable `push()` is actually `returnCopyWithNewElementPushed()`. Which means the *only* way to append is by typedefing.

Comment: @nijansen,Angew: thanks for the response.  Edited post to give a better description of the question.

Comment: @Angew thank you.  I've also resolved my compile error based on yours.  But I'm still trying to see if I can come up with a template Typelist class to wrap the code so that I can access the list as Typelist::type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the actual problem why your code doesn't compile is that you're typedefing the operations, not their results. Change it like this:

```
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type1, A>::type type2;
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type2, B>::type type3;
typedef boost::mpl::push_back<type3, C>::type type4;
```

---

Now the more general view of why you need the typedefs.

Using metaprogramming techniques (like template metaprogramming in your case) requires a mental "shift," because the paradigm is different than "normal" C++. C++ itself is an **imperative** language. Metaprograms are **functional**.

As far as data structures are concerned, the functional paradigm means data structures are *always immutable.* In an imperative language, for example, you do this:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push(4);
v.push(7);
v.push(42);
process(&v);
print(v);
```

In a functional language, the equivalent code would be:

```
v = vector<int>;
v1 = v.push(4);
v2 = v1.push(7);
v3 = v2.push(42);
v4 = process(v3);
print(v4);
```

Or, using more functional notation, something like this:

```
print(process(vector<int>().push(4).push(7).push(42)));
```

In a purely functional (LISP-style) notation, it would be:

```
(print (process (push (push (push (vector<int>) 4) 7) 42)))
```

An alternative way to put it is that in functional languages, data structures aren't *stored,* they are *produced.*

Coming back to C++ template metaprogramming and Boost.MPL, this means the only way to append type `T` to a type list (MPL vector) `v` is to pass `boost::mpl::push_back<v, T>::type` there where you want to handle the "vector with `T` pushed back". To maintain [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you normally do this with a typedef for the "vector with `T` pushed back."

---

Unfortunately, this means there is no way to create a `REGISTER_CLASS` macro the way you'd like to. You could make something similar with a bit more metaprogramming (including use of Boost.Preprocessor).

The idea is to use a Boost.Preprocessor *slot* to hold the last identifier of the type list. Instead of calling the `REGISTER_CLASS` macro directly, it would then be `#include`d, with the class name being passed through another macro. Something like this:

**internal_register.hpp**

```
//This file MUST NOT have include guards

#ifndef CLASS_TO_REGISTER
  #error You must define CLASS_TO_REGISTER before executing REGISTER_CLASS()
#endif

typedef boost::mpl::push_back<
  CURRENT_TYPELIST(),
  CLASS_TO_REGISTER
>::type BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_SLOT(1)));

#undef CLASS_TO_REGISTER

#define BOOST_PP_VALUE BOOST_PP_SLOT(1) + 1
#include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)
```

**registration.hpp**

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<>::type registered0;

#define BOOST_PP_VALUE 0
#include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)

#define REGISTER_CLASS() "internal_register.hpp"

#define CURRENT_TYPELIST() BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, BOOST_PP_SLOT(1))
```

**main.cpp** (or any other usage):

```
#include "registration.hpp"

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

#define CLASS_TO_REGISTER A
#include REGISTER_CLASS()

#define CLASS_TO_REGISTER B
#include REGISTER_CLASS()

#define CLASS_TO_REGISTER C
#include REGISTER_CLASS()

template <typename T> struct wrap {};

struct Print
{
      template <typename T> void operator()( wrap<T> t ) const
      {
            cout << typeid( T ).name() << endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
      boost::mpl::for_each<CURRENT_TYPELIST(), wrap<boost::mpl::placeholders::_1> >( Print() );

      return 0;
}
```

It would take some more tweaking to work correctly when more than one translation unit is involved (some things can't be done at all in such case, some things can be done if appropriate identifiers are put in an anonymous namespace). But it should serve as a starting point.

Comment: +1, It's a great starting point, thank you!  This, though means, I need to have 1 file (probably header) that includes registration.h, a.h, b.h, c.h (all classes) and does registration there.  whenever a new class is added, it needs to add to that file, which might be tough. Also, need to think about e.g. classes in linked .so.

Comment: Also is there any limit as to how many you can push to boost::mpl:: vector? (e.g. you can only do 20, max 50 for boost::variant)

Comment: @surfcode `*` Yes, you can end up generating quite an infrastructure to get such a thing working. But that's to be expected with metaprograms; they're not for the faint of heart. You know the specifics of your project, so only you can weigh the pros and cons of different approaches. `*` As for the limit, the default is 20, but it can be configured via [configuration macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/configuration.html).