# C++14 Metaprogramming: Automagically build a list of types at compile / init time

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, crtp, boost-hana

Using C++14 and some combination of the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) and possibly [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) (or `boost::mpl` if you wish), can I build a list of types at compile time (or static initialization time) without an explicit declaration?

As an example, I have something like this (see it on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12eae6bc335866fb)</kbd>):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>

namespace
{
    struct D1 { static constexpr auto val = 10; };
    struct D2 { static constexpr auto val = 20; };
    struct D3 { static constexpr auto val = 30; };
}

int main()
{
    // How to avoid explicitly defining this?
    const auto list = boost::hana::tuple< D1, D2, D3 >{}; 

    // Do something with list
    boost::hana::for_each( list, []( auto t ) { std::cout << t.val << '\n'; } );
}
```

I want to avoid the explicit list of types -- `D1`, `D2`, and `D3` -- in the creation of `list` because it means I have to maintain that list manually when it seems like I should be able to tell the compiler in or around the class declaration, "Add this class to your running list". (My ultimate aim is to automate factory registration, and this is the missing mechanism.)

Can I do this using some inheritance and/or metaprogramming trickery to compose the list at compile-time or static init time?

Comment: http://b.atch.se/ comes to mind -- but the Committee is trying to patch the loophole that permits such tricks, so you probably shouldn't use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it at compile-time will require "stateful" metaprogramming. In this article [here](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/), Filip Roséen explains how to implement the following using extremely advanced C++14:

```
LX::push<void, void, void, void> ();
LX::set<0, class Hello> ();
LX::set<2, class World> ();
LX::pop ();

LX::value<> x; // type_list<class Hello, void, class World>
```

Also, Matt Calabrese used similar techniques to implements semantic-based concepts in C++11, see the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcsOsV5XSjk&t=31m45s) and [slides](https://github.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/blob/master/thu/Boost.Generic.pdf) at slide #28.

Of course, these techniques rely on a compiler supporting conformant two-phase name lookup.

Alternatively, you can restucture your code to support runtime registration instead, which is much simpler, and can work portably across compilers such as MSVC. This is what libraries such as [Prove](https://github.com/pfultz2/Prove) or [args](https://github.com/pfultz2/args) use. It uses a generic `auto_register` class:

```
template<class T, class F>
int auto_register_factory()
{
    F::template apply<T>();
    return 0;
}

template<class T, class F>
struct auto_register
{
    static int static_register_;
    // This typedef ensures that the static member will be instantiated if
    // the class itself is instantiated
    typedef std::integral_constant<decltype(&static_register_), &static_register_> static_register_type_;
};

template<class T, class F>
int auto_register<T, F>::static_register_ = auto_register_factory<T, F>();
```

Then you can write your own CRTP class:

```
struct foo_register
{
    template<class T>
    static void apply()
    {
        // Do code when it encounters `T`
    }
};

template<class Derived>
struct fooable : auto_register<Derived, foo_register>
{};
```

Comment: Here is a full demo of [this technique in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de4467d26dd02b42). I couldn't get this auto-registration to work as written because `static_register_` was being optimized away, so this is modified slightly. It works on Clang and GCC.

Comment: @metal The issue is the template class may never get instantiated. So adding a default constructor or referring to a function in the base class(ie `this->register_`) is another way to force it.

Comment: @metal So I found that by putting it in a template parameter the compiler will always instantiate the static variable. I have updated the code.

Comment: @PaulFultzII Thanks for finding that trick with the typedef! I spend over a day trying to get something very similar to work and that was the key to getting everything to finally work as it should.

Comment: @PaulFultzII why did you use integral_constant.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to get a compile-time tuple of all types in a namespace or other scope.  To do that, you would need static reflection, which has not yet been added to C++ (but would be very useful as you have discovered).  You can read [one proposal for static reflection here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0194r0.pdf), and the [N4428 proposal here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4428.pdf).

As a workaround, you could write a macro to simultaneously define the type and implicitly add it to the registry during static initialization.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to auto-discover the list on its own. I'm willing to help it out by flagging each with some trigger (e.g., inheriting from a policy class or some CRTP). The thing I'm trying to avoid is hand-maintaining a list of the classes that are auto-registered.

Comment: I could do something like [this with Boost.Preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19630812/201787). Alas, I was hoping for something a little more elegant.

Comment: Yeah, you can inherit from a CRTP class that adds your class to a static list, but you run into initialization-order problems and instantiation depth issues pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of doing this right now is stateful metaprogramming as described [here](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/). But this is tricky, hard to implement and the committee is trying to rule this out as being invalid.

Comment: [Here's a stab at what I was trying to do with CRTP](https://sourceforge.net/p/loki-lib/discussion/93010/thread/bf08774d/), but it doesn't work on more recent compilers. I was hoping further wizardry and C++ arcana could bridge the gap.

Comment: CRTP will allow you to register types at static initialization time, not at compile-time. That may or may not be enough for you.

Comment: Good call: I wasn't distinguishing between static init and compile time, but I should have. Static init time should be sufficient in my case, but still the precise mechanism eludes me. I clarified the wording in my question.