# Disable "unused function" for specific function name

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm compiling project with "Treat warnings as errors".

The problem is, I need incremental type list from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092000/508023

And GCC rightfully complains that a set of declared static functions is neither defined nor used. I don't want to disable this diagnostic completely. Instead, I'd like to disable it only for functions with specific name. Is there such possibility? Maybe some attribute? Or compilation option?

Clarification: I don't need to disable warning for a specified piece of file. I need to disable it for a specific function.

EDIT: I was able to solve my issue by using ADL-based trick. So question isn't actual anymore.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm looking a way to not raise "unused function" warning only for functions with specific name and not for the rest of file completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done with the [`__attribute__((unused))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) GCC extension, as in [the code below](http://goo.gl/wOb859):

```
namespace {
    void f() __attribute__((unused));
    void g();

    void f() {}
    void g() {}
}

int main() {/*f(); g();*/ return 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 you can declare your function with `[[maybe_unused]]`:

```
[[maybe_unused]] void foo (int, int);
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551608/81614