# Incrementally building a typelist in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, typelist

I am trying to find a way to incrementally build a list of types at compile time that can be used at runtime without an obstructive implementation.
The closet solution I have seen is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701798/building-and-accessing-a-list-of-types-at-compile-time/18704609#18704609). The issue for me is the use of the macro since it requires us to add a macro everywhere we define a type we want in our list (error prone and verbose). All of the structures I wish to add to the list will go through a templated function, so ideally if I could build the list there that would solve my issue (no one needs to remember the macro).

I assume the solution is not viable due to the immutable nature of the list (each instantiation of the templated function creates a new list by extending the previous). But my knowledge of template metaprogramming is still limited so possibly there is a feature or technique I have missed.

We are in C++11 so anything there is fine. Boost is available if it helps.

Comment: Any chance we can get a self-contained question, ideally with a clear problem statement? What does "used at runtime" mean?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. I am looking for a mechanism to build a list of types incrementally; similar to the link but without the use of macros (since they would be terribly error-prone in my use case).

"Used at runtime" seems pretty self explanatory. Runtime being when a program is run. Used meaning the construct needs to be usable then (I need to be able to query it to get the type's contained in the construct).

Comment: You could use the non-standard `__COUNTER__` macro to create different names for each step while building the list, then some metaprogramming technique to get the list with the highest `__COUNTER__` value.

Comment: Types in c++ are a compile-time entity. There are no types at runtime (there's only assembly, isn't ?) So you cannot take a type at runtime and use it. You could take **information** about a type, which is what std::type_info (RTTI) does.

Comment: So building a typelist to access its elements at runtime has no sense at all.