# Constructing a compile-time list of templated types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

sorry for the vague wording of the question. I'm running into an issue which seems like it should be solvable, but I'm at a bit of a dead end in my investigation. In short, I'd like to have a compile-time list containing all types which inherit from class A. With that said, I'll jump right into the problem I'm facing.

Say I have two types: Entity and Component.

```
class Entity {
public:
    entity_id id;
    std::vector<component_id> components;
};
```

and

```
template<typename UnderlyingComponentType>
class Component {
public:
     static std::vector<UnderlyingComponentType> components;
     component_id id;
     entity_id containingEntity;
}
```

In a simplfied nutshell, each Entity contains multiple Components, of varying types (e.g. TextComponent, SoundComponent, WeightComponent). Rather than containing these components as fields directly, however, only their IDs are stored within the Entity. This allows for quick iteration over Components of the same type, since they're all in one contiguous vector (e.g. all DescriptionComponents can be traversed in one go). Likewise, any Component of a given type can be retrieved for any given Entity:

```
DescriptionComponent& decription = myEntity.getComponent<DescriptionComponent>()
// Can go to the DescriptionComponent's static vector, and look up the
// appropriate component given our entity's ID (matching it with the component's
// containingEntity ID.)
```

Similar functionality can be provided for deletion of a single component, or addition. However, I run into a problem when I want to delete *all* of the components for a given entity. Because the components are stored outside of the entity, there's not a simple way to say "loop through the components you contain and delete them all". Instead, we have to go to the underlying static vectors for each component type we contain, and delete from there. This is the spot where I've hit a brick wall. It seems like there are two potential solutions here:

1.) Store a collection of types in each Entity which maps to the component vectors for all the Component types we contain (e.g. `entity.getComponentTypes == X<DescriptionComponent, SoundComponent>;` The downside here is that the components per Entity can constantly be changing (I could add a `WeightComponent` at runtime in the above example). As such, I don't believe there's a way to link to the compile-time types based on runtime-type information (like `type_index`es or the like)

2.) Generate a compile-time list of every type which implement Component, then loop through them *all* when an Entity asks to delete all of its Components. For example, say we had an entity `e`, which has ID `123` and contains a `DescriptionComponent` and a `SoundComponent`. We would still have a compile time list of types containing `[DescriptionComponent, SoundComponent, WeightComponent]`, and we would tell each of those Component's static vectors to delete any components referenced by `123`. Since only `DescriptionComponent` and `SoundComponent` vectors had these references, only those two would delete Components, and all the components of `e` would be deleted.

Option 2 above seems like the more feasible option: creating a compile-time list of types. Manually coding this up is easy: a `std::tuple<DescriptionComponent, SoundComponent, WeightComponent>` would easily store and allow me iterate through these types as needed. However, what I'd ideally like is a way to generate this list *programatically*, so that if I later go in and add a `NameComponent`, I won't have to update any other code: it should be automatically managed when I inherit from my templated `Component` class. For example,

```
class NameComponent : public Component<NameComponent> {
    //implementation details
}

//Now, my all-types list should contain [DescriptionComponent, SoundComponent,
// WeightComponent, NameComponent], and I didn't have to update any config.
```

I am not at all sure if the above is possible natively, but any help or resource suggestions would be feasible. I've seen a similar question at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701798/building-and-accessing-a-list-of-types-at-compile), but it relied on macros (which as I understand it, don't interact with templates in the same way). Likewise, if it seems like this is an A/B problem and a simple solution like a `type_index` map actually *would* work, that type of criticism would be more than welcome as well! I'm sure I've overlooked some details or phrased something poorly, so feel free to let me know if/when any more information is needed.

Comment: I believe [boost::hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) may have what you need. Doesn't work under msvc though and it's an extra dependency - but the task you're trying to solve is not simple (until in future we have compile -time reflection)

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I'll check it out, I've heard good things about boost::hana. Good to know that the problem itself has some complexity: compile-time reflection will be a godsend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing `component_id` in the vector in entity, you could use type erasure and store elements that know which Component type to deal with.

```
#include <memory>

struct component_id{};

struct component_type_ref
{
  template <typename Comp>
  component_type_ref()
      : _id(Comp::id), _impl(std::make_shared<_impl_t<Comp>>())
  {
  }

  component_id id() const
  {
    return _id;
  }

  void clear()
  {
    _impl->clear();
  }

private:
  struct _impl_base
  {
    virtual void clear();
  };

  template <typename Comp>
  struct _impl_t : public _impl_base
  {
    void clear()
    {
      Comp::components.clear();
    }
  };

  component_id _id;
  std::shared_ptr<_impl_base> _impl;
};
```

See also https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil

This way, for instance, you can lookup a component id in the vector of an entity and just call clear on it. So might be a solution if there is a know list of operations you want to run on the component types (and those operations do not need to be templates)

If that is not the case, then I am afraid you will need to use type vectors. No need to use tuple here, a simple

`template<typename... T> struct my_type_vector{};`

would be sufficient, probably. But as you wrote yourself, this is not so feasible at runtime.

Comment: This is great, thanks! The idea of leveraging virtual dispatch is something I didn't even consider, but seems like a great fit. Seems like it might even be possible to optimize out the virtual call entirely by passing a std:: function object to the base class constructor. Thanks a ton for the feedback, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad you like it. I am not sure I understand your comment about std::function, though. Do you need the clear() only? Or would you store like half a dozen std::function objects? Just curious...

Comment: Yep, that's what I was suggesting: as long as only one function is needed, might as well pass it in directly rather than rely on virtual dispatch. If more than one is needed, then the overhead for virtual functions is almost certainly less. With that being said, I haven't profiled this concept at all: could turn out that virtual functions are cheaper even in the simple case! No matter what, though, your solution is clean and elegant, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something similar to a `std::type_index` with this:

```
template<typename T>
void type_id() {}

using type_id_t = void(*)();
```

Now in your map, use this:

```
std::map<type_id_t, /* whatever */> myMap;
```

And retrieve like this:

```
auto myElement = myMap[type_id</* somthing else */>];
```

This will do the job without RTTI

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Within this model, though, I don't see how it's possible to deduce the appropriate type from the type_id. For example, if I map `type_id<A> => 123` and `type_id<B> => 456`, I still don't see how I could know to call `A::components.remove(123)` (since I got rid of the template type information when I performed the cast). I hope to be wrong, since this would be great, but I don't see how it could work right now.

Comment: Once type information is striped (by transforming a type to a value) it's not possible to retrieve back the type. But, with `std::map::find` you can remove `123`, because you can search by the value type.

Comment: Hey Guillame: that's a pretty useful way for mapping types to values, but I'm not sure if it is applicable for this particular problem. The main dilemma I'm facing is how to direct these `remove` calls to the appropriate owning vectors. So with the mapping of `type_id` to `component_id`, I'd still need a way to tell the program where the Components with those given `component_id`s should be removed from (should it be from `A::components`?  Or from `B::components`? The map approach doesn't seem to provide a solution here, since these components vectors don't even share a common type).