# Is that possible to know all the name of derived classes?

Tags: c++, templates, reflection

Suppose we have a base class and a bunch of derived classes. Is there any way or mechanism to know all the derived class names programmatically?

Maybe reflection is a good idea, but it's not available on C++. I suppose there will be some kind of template that can finish this job during compilation.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void print(){
        // This function should print all the names of derived class.
    }
    virtual Base* getInstance(string class_name){
        // This function should return an instance related to the class name.
    }
};

class Derived_1 : public Base{ // Suppose we have 100 Derived_X classes, 
                 // so we don't want to add its name to a list manually.
};

int main(){
    Base base;
    base.print(); // This should print the name of all the derived class.
    base.getInstance("Derived_1"); // This should return an instance of Derived_1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, use other language to perform the job.

Comment: even if c++ had reflection, how can a base class possibly know all derived classes?

Comment: Not necessarily to use C++ features to know derived classes. Maybe some design pattern, program mechanism or C++ template can solve this problem.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build something like Factory Pattern. However, it looks ugly. So, I'm puzzling if there's a mechanism to avoid modifying codes in the Factory when adding a new class.

Comment: Related to [building-and-accessing-a-list-of-types-at-compile-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701798/building-and-accessing-a-list-of-types-at-compile-time)

Comment: BTW, each class may register to its Base (Maybe with CRTP).

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem. What do you really want to achieve? Would a factory pattern help your cause?

Comment: @Aziuth No. A Factory Pattern needs us to add wanted class to the factory manually. If I have plenty of classes need to be added to the factory, it will be a waste of time. What I want is make the factory find the desired classes(e.g. Classes inherit from a base class) automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on the fact that it seems you are actually looking for a factory. It uses a small macro to ease classes registration, hope you don't care about it.

**factory.h**

```
#ifndef __FACTORY_H__
#define __FACTORY_H__

#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class B>
class Factory {
  std::map<std::string, std::function<B*()>> s_creators;

public:
  static Factory<B>& getInstance() {
    static Factory<B> s_instance;
    return s_instance;
  }

  template<class T>
  void registerClass(const std::string& name) {
    s_creators.insert({name, []() -> B* { return new T(); }});
  }

  B* create(const std::string& name) {
    const auto it = s_creators.find(name);
    if (it == s_creators.end()) return nullptr; // not a derived class
    return (it->second)();
  }

  void printRegisteredClasses() {
    for (const auto &creator : s_creators) {
      std::cout << creator.first << '\n';
    }
  }
};
#define FACTORY(Class) Factory<Class>::getInstance()

template<class B, class T>
class Creator {
public:
  explicit Creator(const std::string& name) {
    FACTORY(B).registerClass<T>(name);
  }
};

#define REGISTER(base_class, derived_class) \
  Creator<base_class, derived_class> s_##derived_class##Creator(#derived_class);

#endif
```

**example.cpp**

```
#include "factory.h"
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void printName() const { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
  virtual void printName() const override { std::cout << "Derived1\n"; }
};
REGISTER(Base, Derived1);

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
  virtual void printName() const override { std::cout << "Derived2\n"; }
};
REGISTER(Base, Derived2);

int main() {
  std::cout << "Registered classes:" << std::endl;
  FACTORY(Base).printRegisteredClasses();

  std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
  std::unique_ptr<Base> derived1(FACTORY(Base).create("Derived1"));
  derived1->printName();

  return 0;
}
```

*Note*: requires C++11.

Comment: i like this approach! im getting however a ` Access violation reading location` exception when registering a class

Comment: @ThunderWiring My code had a problem about the initialization order of the map (`s_creators`) respect its use by the derived classes. I've change the solution to a singleton, so ensuring the map is created before it's used the first time. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

For the `getInstance` you can declare it a template (needs C++14).  To get all the names of the derived classes in the program you probably have to resort to some preprocessor hack.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base () = default;

  template < typename T,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, void>
             >
    T getInstance() { return T{}; }
};

class Derived : public Base {};
class NotDerived {};


int main(){
    Base base;

    base.getInstance<Derived>();

    // error: no matching member function for call to 'getInstance'
    //base.getInstance<NotDerived>();
}
```

Comment: what is the point of the dynamic cast, when the method returns a `Base*` ?

Comment: @tobi303 Indeed.  It should return `T*` (otherwise the whole method does not make sense).

Comment: it still doesnt make sense to me, because if the instance is a `Base` then casting it to a derived doesnt make much sense, but if it is of derived type then there is no need for that method, it can be casted without it. I guess OP wants to create an instance of a given derived type in the `getInstance`

Comment: @tobi303 Ah, I see.  Then a SFINAE solution is more appropriate I guess.

Comment: ..erm, sorry still doenst make sense. Why would I call `base.getInstance<Derived>();` when I simply can do `Derived{};` ??

Comment: @tobi303 OP only wants this to work for classes which are derived from `Base`.

Comment: OP is asking for a way to create an instance, given the class name as a `std::string`.

Comment: @tobi303 That is not possible.  Types have to be known at compile-time.

Comment: @HenriMenke _Not possible_ is kind of strong... Any kind of program with a runtime type system (interpreters, databases etc) need some way to dispatch function calls to a set of functions that are known at compile time from a user-provided specification that _isn't_ known at compile time. You'd need kind of map from string to callable that returns Base*, so obviously for every derived type in the system you'd need to remember to add the information needed for dispatch to that map.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the name of the derived classes, I propose a solution based on a `BaseList` class/struct, with a static `std::set` (or other container) of names, a template `Base` class/struct, that inherit from `BaseList` and whose template parameter is the derived class (CRTP style) and (to semplify the construction of the derived classes/struct, a C-style macro (I know... macros are distilled evil... but sometimes...) to create the declaration of the derived classes/structs with a necessary static method, that declare the name of the derived class/struct, and a member (that activate the registration of the name).

The following is a full example (unfortunately is a C++11 one)

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct BaseList
 {
   static std::set<std::string> const & derList (std::string const & dn)
    {
      static std::set<std::string> dl;

      if ( dn.size() )
         dl.insert(dn);

      return dl;
    }

   static void print ()
    {
      std::cout << "derived names: ";
      for ( auto const & dn : derList("") )
         std::cout << dn << ", ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 };

template <typename Der>
struct Base : public BaseList
 {
   static std::size_t setNameInList () 
    { return derList(Der::name()).size(); }

   static std::size_t id;
 };

template <typename Der>
std::size_t Base<Der>::id = setNameInList();

#define setDerived(nameDer) \
struct nameDer : public Base<nameDer>\
 { \
   std::size_t idc { id }; \
   static std::string name () \
    { return #nameDer; }

setDerived(Derived_1)
   // other elements
 };

setDerived(Derived_2)
   // other elements
 };

setDerived(Derived_3)
   // other elements
 };

int main()
 {
   BaseList::print();
 }
```

Regarding the `getInstance()` problem, the only solution that I can imagine is the same solution proposed by Enry Menke (+1), so I suggest that you get the instance through a template type parameter.